# Getting Started with Python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I'm just getting started in python with google app engine using the webapp2 framework and jinja2 templating. I can't seem to get my first and very simple script up and running. All I want is for the script to serve the index.html file(located in the same directory).

Here is the app.yaml file:

```
libraries
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

application: practice
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: practice.application
```

Here is practice.py:

```
import os
import webapp2
from jinja2 import Enviroment, FileSystemLoader

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__FILE__)
env = jinja2.Enviroment(loader)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = env.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/', MainPage),
 ], debug=True)
```

Update:
I am running this locally from the Google app engine launcher.
When I attempt to open the file I receive a server error with the description

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:9080/. It may be
down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."
```

Comment: You need to describe what is going wrong ?  An error, no response, a response from the server but not what you expect ?

Comment: Is this deployed code or running locally? What is in your `urls.py` file?

Comment: How do you start the local Google App Engine launcher? Look wherever you start it and see if you can find a log of some kind, and put the output of that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why your code won't run:

- Your app.yaml is malformed
- Enviroment is spelt wrong
- Your missing a closing bracket on line 5
- You haven't imported the jinja2 library
- The variable **__*FILE*__** is undeclared

Here's what I think your code should look like:

app.yaml

```
application: practice
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: practice.application
```

practice.py

```
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__))
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = env.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/', MainPage),
 ], debug=True)
```

I suggest you do the following to make your life a LOT easier:

- download eclipse (I assume you haven't given the syntax errors) -> http://eclipse.org/
- complete the tutorial -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction
- read the docs -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Hope this helps get you on your way.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer! Your suggestions worked perfectly. As you can see, I'm very new to python and web programming in general, and I appreciate you taking the time to help with my elementary mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In *webapp2* you should **use** app instead of **application**, so last line should look like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```